# Output Data in Wait State of Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have an API (lambda+API Gateway) which sits in front of AWS batch and a step function. In my step function I store the job ID from a batch job. My step function closely resembles that of the [Job Status Poller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/job-status-poller-sample.html) example in AWS whereby the step function polls the batch job.

My problem is that I want to do a query on the Step-Function for the BatchJob Id. This is problematic when the step function is in the wait state as this element doesn't have any output.

Is there anyway to output data in the wait state like this ? Or do I need to use a different way of querying the step function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "[GetExecutionHistory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html)" from step function API.
All you need to do is to filter the response by "executionArn" and look for the input in the desired event